# Equivalent expression for "piece of cake"

Tags: expressões, tradução

The expression "piece of cake" is frequently used to denote an easy task or a challenge that has an easy solution.

See some examples of use:

- This game is a piece of cake. I won in 2 hours;
- I finished my homework in 10 minutes. It was a piece of cake;
- I had no trouble finding your house - a piece of cake.

[Reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piece+of+cake)

Is there a similar expression in Portuguese?

Comment: Well, I must admit, that *pedaço de bolo* is **incorrect**, as I've tried it (and subsequently been embarrased :P)

Comment: On the other hand, if something is really difficult you can say "não é bolinho" :) @brazilian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Uma expressão antiga, que pouca gente usa hoje em dia:

> mamão com açúcar

Uma gíria bem comum (pelo menos em São Paulo, Brasil), com o mesmo sentido de *moleza* apontado pelo Renan:

> bico

Exemplo:

> Esse jogo é bico, terminei em 10 minutos

Comment: "mamão com açúcar" foi a primeira coisa que eu pensei quando eu vi a pergunta

Comment: NB: em Portugal não reconheceriam estas expressões.

Comment: Um termo que acho que ainda é usado "fichinha". "- Isso aí é fichinha"

Comment: Verdade @AndréLyra, posta isso como resposta!

Answer (score 26):

In European Portuguese the expressions "é/foi canja [de galinha]" ("it was *canja*") or "sem espinhas" ("without fish-bones") are used to indicate that a task was exceedingly easy to perform.
The first of these makes reference of [this soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canja_de_galinha), which has a pretty straightforward recipe; whereas the second one relates to the fact that eating a fish with no bones is a much easier task than eating one with bones.

> O jogo foi/era canja. Acabei-o em duas horas.
>   Acabei os trabalhos-de-casa em dez minutos. Sem espinhas.

See [this page](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-expressao-sem-espinhas/32797) for reference.

Comment: "Canja" in Brazil is rarely used with this meaning nowadays, but I believe most people can still understand it.

Answer (score 20):

There are many idioms capable of expressing how easy a task is, and different countries and regions will most likely tend to different idioms.

To name a few in European Portuguese:

- "canja" (translates to a *broth*/*soup* with small pieces of chicken, pasta and/or rice, which is very easy to eat) : *"Este jogo é canja, ganhei em 3 minutos."*
- "com uma perna às costas" (*with one leg behind your back* ; again, not to be taken literally) : *"Ganho este jogo com uma perna às costas."*

Comment: "com uma perna às costas" muito bem visto

Answer (score 18):

Eu diria que boa parte dos brasileiros usa *moleza* nesse sentido.

*This game is a piece of cake. I won in 2 hours* por exemplo ficaria *Este jogo é moleza. Venci em 2 horas*

No Rio Grande do Sul também é comum usar *barbada*.

Comment: That's what I thought when I read the question.  I think "moleza" will be understood from Oiapoque to Chui.

Answer (score 10):

To me, an expression that comes to mind with the same meaning is:

> roubar doce de criança (something like "to steal candy from a child")

So, for instance, you can say that a game was so easy that it was like stealing from a child:

> O jogo estava tão fácil que foi como roubar doce de criança.

Comment: In Portugal, it is *É como roubar doces a uma criança.*, meaning something like *It as easy as like stealing candy from a child*

Answer (score 3):

Besides those ones in the other answers, you can also use:

> "sopinha no mel".

e.g.:

> "A prova vai ser sopinha no mel" ("The test is gonna be a piece of cake").

Comment: Or "sopa no mel" mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, eu teria preferido simplesmente comentar numa das respostas acima, mas... falta-me 'reputação' para comentar, então tenho de agregar uma nova resposta. Sorry pela redundância.

Então: em termos de Brasil, e 2015, a expressão "É bico" seria para mim a tradução 'popular' mais imediata.

Comment: Eu, nativo do Rio de Janeiro e tendo sempre vivido aqui, não entenderia "é bico"

Comment: @Centaurus: na resposta dada pelo -bfavaretto- (o 1º q mencionou 'bico'), ele mencionou a regionalidade paulista do termo, de forma q os cariocas talvez fiquem mesmo 'vendidos' nessa expressão. No meu caso, tendo residido por vários anos em BHZ, Santos, Curitiba e Uberaba, acabei construindo um 'mix' pessoal de expressões, onde os regionalismos acabaram por se dissolver ... Abs